# AngularJS required attribute doesn't work on select

Tags: angularjs

I have a following problem with select in my AngularJS application. 
I have set required attribute but it doesn't work on select tag. Doesn't
trigger native validation. Here is my html code:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <form ng-submit="selectChanged()">
        <select ng-model="first" required="required">
            <option>choose</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
            <input type="submit" value="test"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectChanged = function () {

    };
});
```

Here is working jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/k3b5J/3/

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.first = "";
    $scope.selectChanged = function () {
        alert($scope.first);
    };
});
```

You didn't add the variable your `select` is bound to, `$scope.first` in this case.
And the empty option should have a value of `""` --> `<option value ="">choose</option>`

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3b5J/4/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wire-up form validity with submit button, e.g. so it gets disabled when form is not valid

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <form name="myform" ng-submit="selectChanged()">
        <select ng-model="first" required="required">
            <option>choose</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
            <input type="submit" value="test" ng-disabled="!myform.$valid"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I updated your fiddle to reflect that: http://jsfiddle.net/qt8z3/

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when option value is not defined, the text is taken as a value, so, when `choose` is selected, actual value of `first` should be `choose`.

Your code can be fixed like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <form ng-submit="selectChanged()">
        <select ng-model="first" required="required">
            <option value="">choose</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
            <input type="submit" value="test"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

note `value` on `<option value="">choose</option>`

Edit note: when `choose` is selected, value actually exists, so field is filled and it passes required validation.